# how can I use old icon set on ios 7

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, icons, ios7

Apple redesigned toolbar icons for ios 7. My app looks great on ios6 but when I run it on ios 7, toolbar icons (new, open, search etc.) look like different from old ios. Is it possible to use ios 6 icons on ios 7?

Comment: iOS 7 is under NDA, you may ask this question in apple's forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use system icons, those icons come from the system and may change when Apple changes them in iOS. This is by design so that the icons are the same (and recognizable) in all apps.